# Rotate between 2 views

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, ios6

I have two views. How do I transition between them by rotation? I want to rotate the first view to get the second view... Thanks.

I tried using [UIView transitionFromView but it does not have a rotation parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It might be what you are expecting. But, not quite as you expected since it is not using transition animation simply adding or removing the subviews.

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 140, 200, 200)];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:view1];    
UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 140, 200, 200)];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  [self.view addSubview:view2];
view2.alpha = 0;
[UIView transitionWithView:view1 duration:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    view1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
} completion:^(BOOL com){
    view2.alpha = 1;
    [view1 removeFromSuperview];
}];
```